# Question regarding pragma Ident

Tags: c++

Can you please explain what is the meaning of each key in the following declaration

```
#pragma ident "%Z% %M% v%I% (c) GEMS %G%"
```

I am using Clearcase Revision Control System

Comment: While *compiler* are you using? Intel C++ compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pragmas are compiler dependent stuff. This one looks specific to Sun Studio's compiler. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/6n7c46for/):

> Use ident to place string in the .comment section of the executable.

This would mean the executable will contain a string after suitable transformation of the variables (i.e. `%Z%` etc).

Comment: It has something to do with Mercurial.  %I is version, %M is filename.  Very intuitive.

Comment: The original programmer probably was not :)

Comment: HI I need it for ClearCase.My Requirement is that for everycheck in it should update %I% information with proper version number.So that when I run what command on the executables I can see from which version of the file it has created .

Answer (score 1):

These are key words used by the UNIX SCCS source control system. On a UNIX system run `man sccs-get` and it will tell you what all the keywords mean. When you check a file in with `sccs delget` it will replace the keywords with strings. `%Z%` get replaced with `@{#}` which the `what` program uses to display information from an executable. See `man what`.

Comment: IMO this is the right answer: the question was about the meaning of keys, not about the pragma itself, though the meaning of the pragma is also an interesting answer.